# Write a Json file in Java , nested objects instead of String

Tags: java, json

I have to read a sample pom file and write all technology and version in to json file, Im able to get the output in this format:

```
["{ name:junit ,Version:4.12}","{ name:spring-batch-test ,Version:3.0}","{ name:spring-boot-starter }","{ name:slf4j-api }"]
```

However I want to get output in this format:

```
[{ "name":"junit" ,"Version":"4.12"},{" name":"spring-batch-test" ,"Version":"3.0"},{"name":"spring-boot-starter" }]
```

My code :

```java
Map<String, String> dependencies = Maps.newHashMap();
dependencies = populateProjectDepedencies(dependencies, pomFile);
In populateProjectDependencies
for (Dependency dependency : dependencyList) {
    String version = "0.0";
    if (dependency.getVersion() != null && 
        dependency.getVersion().startsWith("${"))
    {
        version = (String) properties.get(dependency.getVersion()
                  .substring(2, dependency.getVersion().length() - 1));
    } else {
        version = dependency.getVersion();
    }
    if (version != null) {
        String a1[]=version.split("\\.");
        int i=a1.length;
        if(i>=2)
        {
            version=a1[0]+"."+a1[1];
        }
        dependencies.put("{name:"+dependency.getArtifactId(),",
                          Version:"+version+"}" );
        JSONArray jsonArray = prepareJsonObject(dependencies);
        genarateTechnologyRadarJson(jsonArray);
        writer.write(jsonArray.toJSONString());
```

Comment: Would be great if you could format the above.  It's totally unreadable.

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you are holding json as `String` array but you want to hold data as `JSONObject` array. So,

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
for (Dependency dependency : dependencyList) {
   .....
   JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
   obj.put("name",dependency.getArtifactId()); 
   obj.put("Version",version);
   ja.put(obj);
   //remove dependencies.put,JSONArray. and genarateTechnologyRadarJson(jsonArray);
}
writer.write(ja.toString());
```

**UPDATE**

This should be your complete code

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Dependency dependency: dependencyList) {
        String version = "0.0";
        if (dependency.getVersion() != null &&
                dependency.getVersion().startsWith("${")) {
            version = (String) properties.get(dependency.getVersion()
                    .substring(2, dependency.getVersion().length() - 1));
        } else {
            version = dependency.getVersion();
        }
        if (version != null) {
            String a1[] = version.split("\\.");
            int i = a1.length;
            if (i >= 2) {
                version = a1[0] + "." + a1[1];
            }
        }
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name",dependency.getArtifactId());
        obj.put("Version",version);
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }

    writer.write(jsonArray.toJSONString());
```

Comment: Is there a specific way I can add my dependencies to dependencyList ?

Comment: what do you mean? @Kirank

Comment: I mean should i put my dependencies map into a list for below?                                                    (Dependency dependency : dependencyList) {

Comment: this is another question you have asked about json. But I presume in my answer that you already have a dependency list. @Kirank

Comment: I tried this way and I see only last entry is displayed in the file:

Comment: private void genarateTechnologyRadar2(Map<String, String> dependencies2)throws Exception {
  JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
  System.out.println("Dependencies are "+ dependencies2);
  JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dependencies2.entrySet()) {

   obj.put("name",entry.getKey());
   obj.put("Version",entry.getValue());
  }
 
writer.write(obj.toJSONString());

Comment: because you create JSONArray every time then of course you will see the last object. Create the JSONArray only once the pass its reference to function I have updated my answer.. @Kirank

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are adding the value as a `String`

```
"{ name:"+dependency.getArtifactId(),"
```

Even, I'm not sure why are you manually constructing the JSON instead just pass the `Map` object to [`JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject(java.util.Map)).

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(yourmap);
```